# PHP-How to solve that Html Page Source is appending to the download file

Tags: php, download

I am downloading a file from Ftp folder after upload.

Problem is when i open the txt file it show s html page source appending with file content

If i preview image file(jpg or jpeg) it shows image is corrupted

If i open pdf error: Failed to load Pdf document

Please let me know where i am wrong.

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && basename($_GET['id']) == $_GET['id']) {
    $filename = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    $filename =NULL ;
}

$err = 'Sorry, the file you are requesting is unavailable.';
if (!$filename) {
    // if variable $filename is NULL or false display the message
    echo $err;
} else {
    // define the path to your download folder plus assign the file name
    $path = '/home/devestctrl/public_html/wp-content/uploads/'.$filename;
    // check that file exists and is readable
    if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path)) {
        // get the file size and send the http headers
        $size = filesize($path);
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
        header('Content-Length: '.$size);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        // open the file in binary read-only mode
        // display the error messages if the file can´t be opened
        $file = @ fopen($path, 'rb');
        if ($file) {
            // stream the file and exit the script when complete
            fpassthru($file);
            exit();
        } else {
            echo $err;
        }
    } else {
        echo $err;
    }
}
```

I checked by using echo of `$filename`;

It shows the output in the file instead of printing in page.

error displays:

> Sorry, the file you are requesting is unavailable.

After error also i can download, but echoed `$filename` displayed in file.

Insert into table:

```
 echo "<tr><a href='?id=" . $row["FileupName"]. "'>".$row["FileupName"]."</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot output data to a page *and* download a file at the same time. One request from your browser will let you do one response. This response is normally displayed in the browser as a page, unless you set the download headers, then the browser will ask you to download the response to a file.

So what you'll need to do is have two requests and responses: In the first, you output your page and a link the user needs to click (or JavaScript or a refresh meta tag to do it automatically) to download the file in a second request.

Comment: I just described it in my second paragraph: In your page, include either a link/button (for the user to click on manually) or some JS or meta tag to trigger a second request, in which you send the actual file.

Comment: 's currenty I have already included a link for the user to download

Comment: Problem is am facing here is after download page is not getting opened.for pdf n txt.  But for txt file it's getting appended with html page source

Comment: Hm, maybe you are using a layout which is already output when you try to send the file? Then you would need to fix your code so that the layout isn't used in this case.

Comment: Can u be more specific about what do u mean by layout

Comment: Then I guess the code which sends the file should be in a plugin which doesn't render the page layout. Then no HTML will be sent as it now appears to happen.

Comment: Thanks cherryDT's I will try all ur suggestion given above....if you find any answer please post it...